# SSL certificate working in chrome but not openssl s_client or curl

Tags: ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04, openssl, curl

Google chromes update to version 58 started invalidating my self signed certificates a few days ago. It was complaining about missing `subjectAltNames`.
I did some research and tried a couple of suggestions (which wouldn't work) but then found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl), the only one that I could get working.

Or did I?

Yay chrome is now accepting my newly generated and imported certificates and I was on my way,

*until*, I hit a page in my `PHP` web app that requires loading data from another micro web-service on the same dev machine.

> stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:

I have been googling and tinkering with this for about 4 hours now and just cannot get my head around it.

**Question**

Why is chrome accepting my certificate. HOWEVER tools like `curl`, `openssl s_client` all giving me `unable to verify the first certificate` or `invalid certificate`? I have tried passing the certificate as a parameter and still apparently invalid.

Debugging with curl and openssl passing the certificate file as a parameter continues to give me this error

> SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20),

I think Im gonna be completely bald by the end of the day.

**Notes**

- The virtual machine is my local development environment so I do have multiple domains with their own cert and keys
- VM sits on IP 192.168.33.10. meaning chrome is not accessing localhost. However curl and openssl s_clinet are trying to access locahost
- Server is a VM running ubuntu 14.04
- Installed self signed certificate on host machine with MMC (Microsofts management console)
- Error is definitely coming from the client class trying to access a web-service.
- I have tried passing the certificate as a parameter and still apparently invalid.
- I am fully aware I can set verify peer to false or pass --insecure to the request but I don't learn anything from that.
- SSL-Session:
  Protocol  : TLSv1.2
- ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` to update certs
- have run `sudo update_ca_ccertificates`
- I have reached frustration level 9000

**Revert update**

I regenerated a new certificate with v3 extension turned off and Back to chrome telling me `subjectAltName` is missing but curl is working. I need to work out how to genrate certs that both curl and chrome will accept.

Comment: @garethTheRed I thought I had done that but I have just outputted my cert and `localhost` is not under the alt names. Let me try that and ill let you know how I get on.

Comment: @garethTheRed still did not work. Does prove that google is authenticating the certificates though. After the update chrome gave the invalid cert error and then once I reinstalled the newly generated one it started working again (in chrome only). Even when I pass the cacert file to curl with the --cacert flag i get `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` So I dont believe its a cacert location issue

Comment: Triple check your /etc/hosts file, maybe?

Comment: thanks @Stephan, but yes an entry of `127.0.0.1 my.domain.dev` is indeed present in the hosts file. anything else in that file required?

when i add -showcerts param to my openssl request i get the expected certificate back. but for whatever reason it cant get issuer.. when its clearly there when you do an `openssl x5... --text`

Comment: @garethTheRed Yeah as I said I installed it with MMC.  I have been passing the crt with the `--cacert` argument and its still saying it cannot get the issuer. I cant see how it could be an installation(adding to trust store) issue if im passing the crt directly? And if its a certificate issue howcome chrome can handle it fine and I can output the content correctly into text. so strange. I might have to set up another VM with same SSL signing method and see if it is replicate-able

Comment: Actually if i revert back to the old certificates and setup i had before adding subjectAltName and its working fine then it must be the way im generating the certificates

Comment: gives me return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate). i only set up  the ssls for my virtual hosts not default/localhost/127.0.0.1.  Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: @garethTheRed i usually use the base64 but i have tried converting to DER to no avail. Ive tried both and they both could be decoded fine. just wont verify

Comment: @garethTheRed i have update my question with the update after re-generating the old certificates.  Curl verifies successfully but chrome is complaining about missing `subjectAltName` again. I need to find out how i can sign subjectAltName without upsetting curl?

Comment: When using `openssl s_client` you should probably use the `-servername`  parameter with the correct name, so that SNI works correctly otherwise the webserver may give you back a certificate for another host that the one you wanted to reach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PatrickMevzek . yes in my hours of debugging and research I came across that as well. You are right. i kept getting the wrong `cert` returned when i was using openssl until I found out about `SNI`. It turned out in the end I had not followed the tutorial correctly and had added additional parameters that were not required,  google chrome must have known how to manage them or ignore the extra params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a [clearer tutorial](http://apetec.com/support/generatesan-csr.htm) that had a much simpler `openssl.conf`. In my original attempts to add `SAN`s I must have un-commented extra lines in the conf that were adding extra info to the certs causing conflicts. Followed this template and my certificate is working all round:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = US
stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = MN
localityName = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default = Minneapolis
organizationalUnitName  = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default  = Domain Control Validated
commonName = Internet Widgits Ltd
commonName_max  = 64

[ v3_req ]
# Extensions to add to a certificate request
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = kb.example.com
DNS.2 = helpdesk.example.org
DNS.3 = systems.example.net
IP.1 = 192.168.1.1
IP.2 = 192.168.69.14
```

Thanks for your comments @garethTheRed. Your comments helped me re-think my approach to debugging this issue.

Even starting a post here helps me lay out what I've tried and helps the brain think up more possible solutions.

Comment: This is my answer and it has resolved my question. SF doesn't let me mark it as correct until after 2 days. In fact its probably a duplicate question and being deleted could be the better option. Although ive never heard of someone have there certificate verifying by one client and not another